# HDD Choice - Single Server - 20 Users

Tags: windows, networking, sas

A client of mine has 3x 300GB 15k SAS Drives in RAID 5 setup. He needs more storage space, and I'd like to replace them given their current age.

I was thinking of replacing them with 3x 1TB 7K SAS Drives RAID 5. Do you think they would notice a speed difference? Network info below

Server: (Only server) Domain Controller, File Server, Print Server, Database server.

Network: Gigabit Switch, 15 Users.

Comment: People will probably tell you to avoid RAID 5.

Comment: `Do you think they would notice a speed difference?` - This can't be answered objectively. Does the client have existing performance issues? If so, what are the performance problems related to? Printing, file access, DNS lookups, Etc.? If there is an existing performance issue have you isolated it to the disk subsystem? Putting in faster disks isn't going to help if the performance problem is network related. You need to do some performance measuring and analysis to determine **A:** Is there an existing performance problem? **B:** What's the cause of that performance problem?

Comment: Why not SSD instead of 15K SAS?

Comment: Can't say I ever jumped on the RAID 5 hate wagon.  Especially with SAS, hard drive failure tolerances are leaps ahead of where they used to be.  A RAID 5 array of 3 SAS drives honestly will probably function for the lifetime of the hardware and still be more limited by the controller backplane than the actual drives.

Comment: Apologies, right now they have no speed issues (or rather they're used to the speed they have). I'm not looking to boosting their current speed, but rather looking to increase their storage space without impacting their current speed to a noticeable extent. (Thus SSDs are not an option, due to cost/size) They are also a "frugal" client, so cost is a factor, and the cause of this question. I think I kinda understand the preference of RAID 10 v RAID 5, but I'd have to check if it could support 4 SAS Drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest to avoid RAID5 in favor of RAID10. Simply buy 4x 2TB enterprise-grade SATA disk (eg: WB Re or, on the cheap side, WD RED Pro) and your customer will not only have much more space, but the system will be way faster also.

As a note: when used as Domain Controller, Windows disables the disk's private cache. For maximum speed, please ensure that your RAID card has a battery-backupped write-back cache (and enable it).

Comment: I've talked with them and it sounds like they're going to push for a server replacement at the end of the year, so a drive replacement might not happen. Could you expand on RAID5 vs RAID10 though? I understand there's a speed boost, but why else would RAID10 be better?

Comment: RAID10 is way faster than RAID5 on small random writes. Moreover, its performance are much less dependent on fast BBU-enabled RAID controller, so with RAID10 you can go with cheaper/older RAID cards. Moreover, RAID5 is more prone to failures (but with only 3x 300GB disks failure rate should be very low anyway).